# how to hide column header if value set is null in pentaho report designer

Tags: null, expression, formula, pentaho, is-empty

I want to hide headers in the details header pane that have null values in the details pane.

I tried 

`=IF(ISBLANK([10]);"False"; "True")`

but this only checks the first value of the value set.

oct |  null   | dec

1   |  null   |   1

1   |  1    |  1

i also tried 

`=IF(ISEMPTYDATA([10]);"False"; "True")`

but displays the header when there is no data for example

[i dont want oct displayed if null] https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8gQA.png